# Unity Zoom In And Out 2D

Tags: c#

Been trying for a while now and I just need to make it so I can zoom in and out using the camera's FOV.
When I try this nothing happens.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera cameraFreeWalk;
    public float zoomSpeed = 20f;
    public float minZoomFOV = 10f;

    public void ZoomIn()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
        {
            cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView -= zoomSpeed;
            if (cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView < minZoomFOV)
            {
                cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView = minZoomFOV;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw I just started using Unity yesterday so I barely know anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Since there is nothing calling the ZoomIn() function, nothing will happen. You should move the Input-check into the Update() method since it is called by Unity in every frame, and you can then call the ZoomIn() function when the mouse-wheel is turned up.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
    {
        ZoomIn();
    }
}

public void ZoomIn()
{
    cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView -= zoomSpeed;
    if (cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView < minZoomFOV)
    {
        cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView = minZoomFOV;
    }
}
```

(2) You need to set the cameraFreeWalk field. You can either make it visible in the editor by adding the attribute "SerializeField", and then in the editor drag the Camera into the exposed field...

```
[SerializeField]
private Camera cameraFreeWalk;
```

... or you can collect the Camera component automatically. In this example, we tell Unity that there must be a Camera component on the same game object and we collect a reference to it in the Awake() method. If you want to be extra careful, check that you really have got a reference by doing an Assert() check. A bit redundant because of the RequiredComponent attribute, but I like to check all fields I am working with.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class cameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    ....

    private void Awake()
    {
        cameraFreeWalk = GetComponent<Camera>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(cameraFreeWalk);
    }
```

(3) Finally, to be sure that the script works, you should also in the Awake() method, check that someone hasn't changed the camera to Orthographic - since then FOV will not be used. Personally, I like the Assert() method as you can see...

```
    Assert.IsFalse(cameraFreeWalk.orthographic, "There isn't a FOV on an orthographic camera.");
```

The complete solution would then be something like this...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class cameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera cameraFreeWalk;
    public float zoomSpeed = 20f;
    public float minZoomFOV = 10f;
    public float maxZoomFOV = 160f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        cameraFreeWalk = GetComponent<Camera>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(cameraFreeWalk);
        Assert.IsFalse(cameraFreeWalk.orthographic, "There isn't a FOV on an orthographic camera.");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
        {
            ZoomIn();
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
        {
            ZoomOut();
        }

    }

    public void ZoomIn()
    {
        cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView -= zoomSpeed;
        if (cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView < minZoomFOV)
        {
            cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView = minZoomFOV;
        }
    }


    public void ZoomOut()
    {
        cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView += zoomSpeed;
        if (cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView > maxZoomFOV)
        {
            cameraFreeWalk.fieldOfView = maxZoomFOV;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.